# Dynamic colour picker in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a colour picker that I use on a picture with `MouseMove` rather than `Click` event so as to allow the colour to be displayed "on the fly", however when I leave the bounds of the image, I am getting an error and cannot think of the best way to handle it.

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
        If isWithin(DirectCast(sender, PictureBox), New Point(e.X, e.Y)) And e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            Dim bmptmp As New Bitmap(Me.PictureBox1.Image, Me.PictureBox1.Width, Me.PictureBox1.Height)
            Dim clrtmp As Color = bmptmp.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y) '<--- error here
            ...
            ...
        End If
End Sub
```

I wrote the `isWithin` function and added it to the `If` above as one possible way of checking, but this doesnt seem to work:

```
Public Function isWithin(pic As PictureBox, pnt As Point)
    Dim rct1 As New Rectangle(pic.Top, pic.Left, pic.Width, pic.Height)
    Dim rct2 As New Rectangle(pnt.X - 1, pnt.Y - 1, 1, 1)
    Return rct1.IntersectsWith(rct2)
End Function
```

Error I am receiving is

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll - Additional information: Parameter must be positive and < Height
```

(or `< Width` if I go too far right). I assume this is because either `e.X` or `e.Y` is no longer either greater than 0 or less than the height or width (which is what I was trying to check with the `isWithin` function)

Comment: might be nice to know *which* error you are getting.  you might have others on the horizon as there are some resources there which may not be properly disposed of.

Comment: @Plutonix Ah yes, will recreate in a minute to get the error. As i solved it already, I forgot to include it at the end of the post

Comment: @Plutonix added that error message now

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out as I was typing the question but thought I would still add it anyway. Enclosed it in `Try... Catch ex as Exception... End Try` and then it worked fine. No need to actually handle the error as it's an expected error, just me being sloppy and coming at it from a VBA thought train (*"Do... or do not. There is no try."* - Yoda & VBA)

Comment: Also this makes my `isWithin` function redundant, so have removed that from the final code